# Rebuild node.js sha1 on terminal

Tags: bash, node.js, sha1

I have a REST API in node.js. It can CRUD clients and saves an encrypted key like this:

```
// Let's sha the value.
var crypto = require('crypto')
  , shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');

shasum.update(clientId + apiKey);

 // My hashed value:
shasum.digest('hex');
```

I want to have a shell script, that can perform the same WITHOUT touching the API.

I have tried this:

```
echo '1000apikey' | openssl sha1 -hex
```

But it results in a different hashed values (if clientId is 1000 and apiKey is "apikey"). Why's that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo '1000apikey'` adds a newline character at the end of the string and that gets hashed too. Try `echo -n '1000apikey' | openssl sha1 -hex`.

Comment: Now that you seem to be a pro: This command somehow redirects to stdin, how would I assign the hash to a var?
   
    hash=$(echo -n $1$2 | openssl sha1 -hex);

redirects to a stdin and not to my var ...

Comment: Just tested `hash=$(echo -n $1$2 | openssl sha1 -hex)` and it works fine, result is available in `$hash`.

Comment: Hm, did not work in my code. I get a result in like `(stdin) hashvalue` and can't access the var.

However, I solved it like this:

`read -r source hash < <(printf %s "$1$2" | openssl sha1 -hex);`